# Log Shipping Status Not Auto Refreshing After 2019 Upgrade

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

After upgrading to SQL Server 2019, 'Transaction Log Shipping Status' report stopped auto refreshing. Does anyone have any suggestions what I should look for?